# SEO-bots content reading question

Tags: search-engines, dynamic

I got a preety noobish question..
I have a web site and most of the content that is shown to a user is drawn from a database..
And the pages that i sent to eg. google to index have a querystring in their url..

Meaning when the page is opened, most of the content shown is from a database using a query, and querys key info is from a querystring..

Does eg. googlebot index a page WITH the content from the database, or just the plain html content before the server side activity is done?

Tnx for the anwsers, and sorry for the noobish question :)

Comment: Just changed the tags, this isn't really seo-related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search engines see what your users see as they are no different from them. They request a page and the page's content is delivered to them. Remember, server side stuff happens *before* the page is served.

Query strings are part of the URL and search engines always include them when crawling a site so unless you link to the page without the query string, or submit it without it, they will only crawl the pages with the query strings in place.

Comment: yeah i thought so.. just wanted to be sure.. tnx, your anwser will be marked in approx. 7 minutes :) (site won't let me do it before)